# atomでCentOS上のGit管理下のファイルを編集する

Tags: linux, git, atom-editor, filesystems

Windows7でatomを使用しています。
ローカルにあるGit管理下のファイルは当然編集できるのですが、
CentOS上にあるGit管理下のファイルを直接編集する方法はありますか？

現在は、ローカルにある作業ディレクトリでコミットしたものなどを、
CentOS上の共有リポジトリにプッシュしています。
それを、CentOS上に作業ディレクトリを作ってそこで作業したものを、
CentOS上の共有リポジトリに反映するようにしたいです。

何か方法はありますでしょうか？

Comment: sshfsを使うとリモートのファイルを直接編集できます。Windows用にはwin-sshfsというものがありますが試したことはありません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

h2so5さんからのコメントで解決。

下記URLを参考にwin-sshfsをインストールしました。
http://www.maruko2.com/mw/Windows_%E3%81%A7_sshfs_%E3%82%92%E5%88%A9%E7%94%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95